# I have 300,000 columns in a tsv file, I only need 10,000 of them.

Tags: python, r, parsing, csv

They all start with "rsid_set(variable)". I have little to no coding experience but have been trying to use R and python. Are there any quick ways to getting those columns that I want?

Follow-up: Is there a way to take the means of each column and turn it into a normal distribution with 10,000 values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# read in
df <- read.tsv("path/to/your/file")

# select only colnames beginning with rsid_set
df <- df[grep("^rsid_set",colnames(df)),] 

Your follow-up, I don't understand. You'll have to clarify what you want.

# Take the means of each column:
means <- colMeans(df)

# normal distribution with 10k values
norms <- rnorm(10e3)
```

Comment: Awesome! This look great. I have been using read.table, would that work as well or would it be slower? I actually am changing my follow-up. The values in these columns are numbers between 0-3 (e.g 1.27, 0.76, 2.1). I would like to find the number of data in each column that is over 2.5 . So there are 10,000 columns. Let's say there are 3,000 rows. Say there are 12 numbers in a column that are over 2.5 . I would like to find out for each column, how many numbers are over 2.5 and then make a normal distribution of that number. Does that make sense?

Comment: I really hate telling people to RTM, but I think you would be much better served by taking the next 4 hours to go through a few of the basic R tutorials out there.

Comment: Sorry for the follow-up, I asked in a different thread and got an answer. I guess I was just asking if read.table is significantly slower than read.csv? I know it is, but what's a rough estimate of difference for a 300,000 column and ~4000 row file?

Comment: `read.csv` IS `read.table` with different function defaults, namely: `sep=","`

Comment: It's regex that signifies the beginning of a line. `$`, the end.  You can find descriptions of all available regex in `?regex`.